# .Net Application cannot detect ODP.NET 2.111.6.20 in 64bit windows

Tags: .net, deployment, odp.net

We are currently deploying our .net winform application which depends on ODP.NET 2.111.6.20 via xcopy. Installing on 32 bit windows was fine, however, for some reason our applications cannot detect odp.net in a 64bit environment.

I would like to ask if there are special build configurations that i have to do in building my applications to solve this problem, or do i have to tweak a settings file or two to make it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ODP is compiled separately for 32 and 64 bits so aside from having different builds referencing the correct library I'm not sure what you could do. I forced my builds to 32 bits since supporting 64 wasn't a hard requirement; programs in 32 bits run just fine on 64-bit windows (of course you must be careful with registry access and all other things that differ between 32 and 64).

Comment: Thanks, I also ended up rebuilding my applications to target 32 bit only. Apparently, the ODP.NET I installed in the client machine is ODACfor visual studio, which i think is 32bit. The 64 bit odp.net is also available, however it is only available in metalink (i don't have an account in metalink)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692153/oracle-odp-net-version-agnostic-alternative/3696588#3696588 for an alternative to having anything installed on the client at all.