# Alternates to the Oracle .net data provider?

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net

The oracle .net client is a big pain to install and manage.   So what experience have people got with alternatives?

*(Telling the customer that you only support Sql Server is not always an option)*

Comment: Oracle seems to have got their act together on this, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odac-12cr2-data-sheet-2088814.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Why alternatives? The ODP.Net provider from Oracle works. I've provided some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692153/oracle-odp-net-version-agnostic-alternative/3696588#3696588). If there are any interesting requirements we could discuss further of course.

Comment: It may work after it has been installed, however installing it is a pain and often needs a oracle dba to get it working.  It is also a large install with a 101 different config files.

Comment: Umm.. did you read the post I linked to? If you include ODP.Net in your project's output i.e. besides your .exe file, and if you include OCI as well, you don't need anything installed prior to your application connecting to Oracle.